# Synchronise a method with two instances of the same class

Tags: java, synchronization, threadpool

Here, I am trying to use the Obj class to create multiple instances of Obj which then try to access the justOne method in a class called sync. However, I don't want two of these objects to be able to access the method at the same time.

I thought that by adding  `synchronized` to my justOne method that I would be preventing multiple instances accessing the method at the same time, but I am getting an `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

How can I change my code such that only one instance of Obj can access justOne at one time?

Here is my Obj class:

```
 public class Obj implements Runnable {
        public Sync sync;
        public void run() {
            sync.justOne(this);
        }
    }
```

Here is my justOne method:

```
public synchronized void justOne(Obj o) {
    while(!condition) {
        try {
           o.wait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
    }
    // Do something with o  
 }
```

Comment: `while (condition = false)` is almost certainly your first problem.  `while (!condition)` is what you want.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, that was just stupid on my part. The problem is still not fixed though!

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve exactly? It looks to me that "only one instance of the same class has to [...]" hides a more fundamental problem, and that this is the problem you should be exposing, not your attempted solution. In other words, a XY problem.

Comment: You don't need `wait()` for that if all the `Obj` objects share the same `sync` instance. A `synchronized` method guarantees that all calls to it will be processed sequentially.

Comment: @fge I'm not sure how that's a problem... The program will create multiple objects of type Obj. Each Obj will then try to access the justOne method, but I only want one instance to be able to access the method at a given time.

Comment: @Titus Okay... But how do I then make the thread halt if condition is not satisfied?

Comment: The question remains anyhow: why did you judge that this `justOne()` method was the way to go? Again: before asking about a potential solution, please expose your problem

Comment: @fge I'm not really saying it's the best way to go. I'm trying to learn about how threads and synchronization work and this is something that I'm struggling to understand.

Comment: In that case, you need to use `wait()`, and to call `wait()`, you need to synchronize on the object you want to wait on, ex: `synchronized(o){o.wait()}`

Comment: In 2016, to be honest, there is _no reason at all_ to be concerned about such details: the JDK provides sufficiently enough primitives (in `java.util.concurrent`) that attempting a home made solution is nothing else but a waste of time. That said, if you want to see how low level synchronization is handled, then feel free to explore the source code of, for instace, `wait()` and `notify()`; but you'll find that at low levels anyway those are native calls. The rest is Java -- literature. Anyway, even though it's old, there exists one reference to read: JCIP

Comment: @Titus Thank you for that, I've managed to make progress now!

Comment: @fge I understand what you mean, I just thought it was something interesting to look into! Thanks for your points though.

Comment: Just synchronize on the class. You don't need wait/notify or semaphores at all. Even make the method `static synchronized`.